# Как правильно задать значение инпуту?

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь задать значение инпуту, но значение не записывается, хотя в переменной message есть текст, как можно это исправить?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var message = "";
    $( ".class" ).click(function() {
        $('.class1.class2.class3').each(function(){
            message+=$(this).html()+';';
        });

    });
    $("input[name='all_prod']").val('1'+String(message)+'1');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var message = "";
    $(".class").click(function() {
        $('.class1.class2.class3').each(function() {
            message += $(this).html() + ';';
        });
        $("input[name='all_prod']").val('1' + message + '1');
    });
});
```