# Почему не срабатывает .click на второй кнопке?

Tags: jquery

У меня есть пару кнопок при нажатии на которые должно всплывать модальное окно, но при нажатию на первую с заданным id всё работает а на второй нет. Что я делаю не так?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#modalBtn").click(function() {
            $("#myModal").css({'display':'block','z-index':'10000000000000'});
         });
         $('.close').click(function(){
            $("#myModal").css({'display':'none','z-index':'10000000000000'});
         });
```

html код:

```
<div class="more"><a id="modalBtn"><span class="align-elem">Уточнить стоимость</span></a></div>
<a id="modalBtn"><span class="align-elem">Рассчитать стоимость</span></a>
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1129465/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `$("#modalBtn")` возвращает объект jQuery, содержащий максимум один элемент с таким `id`.

Comment: Спасибо, а подскажите как сделать чтобы работало на все элементы?

Comment: @Develop Покажите хоть немного html-а.

Comment: добавил в вопрос, спасибо

Comment: @Develop Где находятся `"#myModal"` и `'.close'`?